# How to get username and user email in my form Django

Tags: python, django

I have "creating order form" which is need email and username to purchase.
I want to push request username and user email into this form (if user is authorized)

forms.py

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Имя пользователя', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='E-mail', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    vk_or_telegram = forms.CharField(label='Введите ссылку на vk или telegram для связи с админом',
                                     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

    captcha = ReCaptchaField()


    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'vk_or_telegram')
```

views.py

```
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product=item['post'], price=item['price'])

            cart.clear()
            return render(request, 'store/orders/created.html', {'order': order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()

    return render(request, 'store/orders/create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

[template of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WvU3.png)

Comment: What is not working at this moment? The form looks correct, with the correct fields, and upon calling `form.save()` the username and email should be populated, if the user has filled it in (which they have to, because they're required).

Comment: at the screenshot "template of form" i have empty forms which is needed when user is not authorized, but now im authorized on my site and i want to form automatically push my username and email into empty fields

Comment: I've added a solution which I believe will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give initial parameters to the form, which will be prefilled in the form.

First, check if the user is authenticated and if so, push the initial values to the form using the `initial` argument.

```py
def order_create(request):

    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # ...
    else:

        # only if the user is logged in, we prepopulate the form
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            initial = { 
                'username' : request.user.username,
                'email' : request.user.email
            }
        else:
        # else, we just give an empty dict
            initial = {}
        
        form = OrderCreateForm(initial=initial)
        
    # ...
```

However, ask yourself the question if this is the best approach for your problem. Any user can still alter the `username` and `email` field to something else. If you don't want users to be able to manipulate the fields, you could use a ForeignKey to the user table for each order.

Comment: Thanks I’ll try this solution but yes it’s the best way bcs I want to unauthoriized users be able buy on my store as well